# Creating a Nested for Loop for Use in Scraping in R

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops

I am having trouble executing a nested for loop to create a list of stems for use in a scrape.  The simple data frame contains 2 variables, name and number of photos.  I want the code to spit out a list/matrix of the stems like this:

Alex/1
Alex/2
Alex/3
Alice/1
.....

I can get it to work when doing the rows one at a time but unfortunately I cannot figure out how to do it through the loop of all the names.

Any help would be super appreciated and will hopefully be used by anyone who wants to scrape HTML with this structure!

**Here is my code thusfar:**

```
stems<-list()
for(Name in data$Names){
    for(Photo in data$Photos)
    stems[Photo]<-print(paste(Name,1:data$Photos,sep="/"))
}
stems.matrix<-as.matrix(stems)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want? I know you said you wanted a list, but I think a vector of characters is just as easy.

```
#I'm guessing your data looks something like this...
data <- data.frame( Names = c("Simon" , "Alex" , "Ben", "Dave") , Photos = c( 4 , 3 , 2 , 3) , Misc = c( 4 , 3 , 4 , 4 ) )

#Use apply rather than nested loops
stem.list <- unlist( apply( data , 1 , function(x) { i <- 1:x[2]; paste( x[1] , i , x[3] , sep ="/") } ) )
```

Which gives...

```
> stem.list
 [1] "Simon/1/4" "Simon/2/4" "Simon/3/4" "Simon/4/4" "Alex/1/3"  "Alex/2/3"  "Alex/3/3" 
 [8] "Ben/1/4"   "Ben/2/4"   "Dave/1/4"  "Dave/2/4"  "Dave/3/4"
```

Comment: This is exactly it!  Thank you so much Simon!

Comment: This works perfectly; I just have one addition -- what if you want to another part to this so it would end up Simon/1/4, Simon/2/4...

Comment: Where is the 4 coming from? Is it another value in an additional column. Do all people have the same value at the end, i.e. `/4` or is it different for different people? If it's just say 4 for everyone, just add to the paste part, so `stem.list <- unlist( apply( data , 1 , function(x) { i <- 1:x[2]; paste( x[1] , i , 4 , sep ="/") } ) )` if it's different and the value comes from another column in the dataframe (in this case the 3rd column ) use `stem.list <- unlist( apply( data , 1 , function(x) { i <- 1:x[2]; paste( x[1] , i , x[3] sep ="/") } ) )`

Comment: I have now edited the answer to reflect the additional changes you wanted.

Comment: Simon- the four in this example is just the number of photos. Your code works perfectly; thank you so much!!

Comment: Simon- you should probably have tagged @abresler in your comment. Maybe he'll see now.

Comment: @abresler If this worked for you I'd really appreciate it if you can please just press the green tick next to my answer so everyone knows this is answered. I will also then get the reputation points for taking time to answer. Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delay!  Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 dat <- data.frame(name=letters[1:4],photo=1:4)
 dat.ex <- expand.grid(dat)
 paste(dat.ex[,1],dat.ex[,2],sep='/')
 [1] "a/1" "b/1" "c/1" "d/1" "a/2" "b/2" "c/2" "d/2" "a/3" "b/3" "c/3" "d/3" "a/4" "b/4" "c/4" "d/4"
```